# How to test apps script addon

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-addons

I have created an addon using [this](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate) guide.

*code.gs*

```
function onOpen() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
   .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar');
}

function showSidebar() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle('Sample');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Works</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

It says "If you switch back to document and reload you will see a submenu under **Add-ons** menu.

But I could not find my addon submenu, I think the quickstart guide is outdated.

Please guide me, How to test the addon on google sheet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `onOpen` function is incomplete; `.addToUi();` is missing.

This is the `onOpen` function on the referred guide

```
/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Fixed the issue but still, no menu is displayed.

Comment: @SameerKhan Try using Chrome in incognito mode. If it still doesn't work, look at the script execution to see if there is an error and in such case please edit the question to include the textual error message.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved It**

Found guidance from [this article](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons)

In order to test

1. Switch back to the legacy editor
2. Select **Run** > **Test as add-on**
3. Configure Test

   **Select version:** Test with latest code
   **Installation Config:** Choose any of the option
   **Select Doc:** Select your sheet
   Save
4. Execute Saved Test > Test